# More readable way for null reference checks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-readability, human-readable

In a lot of apps I write, I find myself assigning a default value for a subclass of a DBML object. Here is an example of the current way I'm having to do it:

```
var viewModel = new RandomViewModel
{
    ContactName = (Order.Customer != null ? Order.Customer.ContactName : "Unknown"),
    Date = Order.OrderDate,
    Shipper = (Order.Shipper != null ? Order.Shipper.CompanyName : "Fedex"),
    ShipCity = Order.ShipCity,
    ShipRegion = Order.ShipRegion,
    FirstCategory = (Order.OrderDetails.First().Product.Category != null
        ? Order.OrderDetails.First().Product.Category.CategoryName
        : "DefaultCategory",
    ItemCount = Order.OrderDetails.Count
};
```

Ideally it would be most readable as this:

```
var viewModel = new RandomViewModel
{
    ContactName = Order.Customer.ContactName ?? "Unknown",
    Date = Order.OrderDate,
    Shipper = Order.Shipper.CompanyName ?? "Fedex",
    ShipCity = Order.ShipCity,
    ShipRegion = Order.ShipRegion,
    FirstCategory =
        Order.OrderDetails.First().Product.Category.CategoryName
        ?? "DefaultCategory",
    ItemCount = Order.OrderDetails.Count
};
```

but there is a NullReferenceException for any foreign keyed object that is null. I don't think null coalescing is usable here, but is there some other consise way to accomplish this very frequent task? Perhaps with a class/method extension, or even a VS macro?

I used the Northwind database for this example:

[image: northwind db]

Open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach to take.  Declare `partial class Order`, with properties like this:

```
string CustomerNameOrDefault { get { return Customer != null ? Customer.ContactName : "Unknown"; } }
```

Then your code becomes:

```
var viewModel = new RandomViewModel
{
    ContactName = Order.CustomerNameOrDefault,
...
```

Comment: This is a good idea - although i think the ideal answer is if it's possible to make it generic. And yet, only do it for properties that are generated by the DBML from a foreign keyed ID field, and that the ID is also Nullable. I'll be attempting that

Answer (score 0):

> Open to any and all suggestions.

Personally I use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map between my domain models and view models. Your code could now become:

```
RandomViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<Order, RandomViewModel>(Order);
```

Comment: I have considered AutoMapper in the past, but never tried. One database many of our apps integrate with is a legacy one with terrible naming conventions (all column names eight letters with inconsistent abbreviations).  So I believe most all AutoMapping would need custom mapping - and seems to make the code even more complex and less readable.

It is a good library for many others though